# How to Replace Web Service Binding - Tuscany SCA with Spring from scratch

Tags: spring, web-services, java-ee-6, sca, apache-tuscany

I have had some experience of developing web services (standalone) which are called via angularjs single page apps. But, I now have a Java EE task which involves the following:
1. Removing a Tuscany SCA web service binding from some business components e.g. Customer, Accounts. The components are exposed as web services
2. Replacing the Tuscany Binding with a Spring Injection web service binding.

NOTE: The decision to replace Tuscany SCA with Spring is already made.
But, as a developer with experience of developing web service without any knowledge of the binding frameworks. I need some understanding of what these frameworks are, how I can wire this framework to my web service from scratch.
I don't just want to copy and paste and do try and error on a commercial project.
I am afraid, there was no KT, hence I am learning this the hard way!
Please, can someone help me in understanding this underlying framework or binding. 
What are this binding or binding frameworks?
Why do we need them?
How is Tuscany SCA different from Spring?
Any help good, practical, code sample, online references etc will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear with concept of SOA, SCA and Tuscany.

First understand which type of webservice is written in your project whether RESTFul or SOAP. And then understand how SCA + Tuscany service is written for for RESTFul/SOAP service and then try to remove Tuscany from it.

Reference docs:

1. http://tuscany.apache.org/documentation-2x/sca-java-bindingrest.html
2. http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration